Token Not Set in Browser Cookies in Production
I am working on a React application where I handle authentication by setting a token in cookies after the user logs in. I have set the token in cookies its getting set in local development. when its come to the production the token will not get set in the browser cookies. We have the two docker Images, one is for front end and one is for the backend. But the main Problem is my token is not getting set in Cookies.
My Environment:
Backend: Spring Boot and MySQL.
Frontend: React Js.
Api Handling:-=RTK Query.
Cloud Provider: Google Cloud Provider.
Cookie library: js-cookie
Verified the backend response contains the token.
Ensured the secure and sameSite attributes are set correctly(I have Removed Everything While Set the token).
Checked that my domain and subdomain match correctly.
checked that everything working fine in local.
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { authApis } from "./authApis";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
const initialState = {
  token: Cookies.get("accessToken") || null,
  isLoggedIn: !!Cookies.get("accessToken"),
  successMessage: "Logeed in",
  errorMessage: "",
};
const setToken = (token) => {
  Cookies.set("accessToken", token, {
    // sameSite: "Strct",
    // secure: true,
  });
  console.log("accessToken", token);
};
const deleteCookie = (name) => {
  Cookies.remove(name, { path: "/" /*sameSite: "Strict"*/ });
};
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      authApis.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        const { token } = action.payload;
        state.token = token;
        state.isLoggedIn = true;
        console.log("token", token);
        setToken(token);
        //below everything is consoling
        console.log("Token retrieved:", state.token);
        console.log("Token Get set", Cookies.get("accessToken"));
      }
    );
    builder.addMatcher(
      authApis.endpoints.logout.matchFulfilled,
      (state, action) => {
        state.token = null;
        state.isLoggedIn = false;
        deleteCookie("accessToken");
        deleteCookie("roles");
        deleteCookie("isAdminView");
        console.log("Logout successful:", action.payload);
      }
    );
  },
});
export default authSlice.reducer;

